# What is the best practice to upgrade EXT:powermail 2.3.3 to 6.1?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, powermail

I'm currently upgrading a TYPO3 6.2 installation to 8.7. Since it's a huge website I've made a copy and started the upgrade there. I've switched the installation from non-composer to composer mode.

Now I need to update EXT:powermail from 2.3.3 to 6.1.

To get hold of all database changes I did the upgrade step by step:

```
composer require in2code/powermail "^3"
./typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
./typo3cms extension:setup powermail
composer require in2code/powermail "^4"
./typo3cms cache:flush --force
./typo3cms extension:setup powermail
composer require in2code/powermail "^5"
./typo3cms cache:flush --force
./typo3cms extension:setup powermail
composer require in2code/powermail
./typo3cms cache:flush --force
./typo3cms extension:setup powermail
```

My question now is how to do these database migrations again when I do the final upgrade of that website with the production database.

Currently my approach would be to remove EXT:powermail prior to the final upgrade and do the above mentioned steps with the production database again.

Are there any better proposals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating from 2.x to 6.x should be very easy. Just update your system first with the newest powermail version. Because we removed the migration, you would have to manually rename existing database tables of powermail: https://gist.github.com/einpraegsam/a02bb69c29aa747de4ffb613704bbd7a

Comment: So first step would be to do the database migration as described in your Gist and than install the latest powermail version and do the other database changes? Or are there non except of the table renaming?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't matter in my eyes. If you update powermail first, the empty tables are created automaticly. And afterwards you have to copy the values into the new tables (or remove the new tables if you want to ensure to really have all needed fields).